# How to turn a ResultSet into a DTO ArrayList

Tags: java, database, arraylist, resultset

I have a ResultSet from a Database that contains 6 columns for each row.

For me, each row is an object and each column is a parameter for that object.

The question is, I'm trying to do it with this code:

```
while(rs.next() && i<25){
        aux.setIdVinilo(rs.getInt("id_vinilo"));
        aux.setTitulo(rs.getString("titulo"));
        aux.setAutor(rs.getString("autor"));
        aux.setGenero(rs.getString("genero"));
        aux.setFecha(rs.getInt("fecha"));
        aux.setDiscografica(rs.getString("discografica"));
        aux.setImagen(rs.getString("imagen"));

        historial.add(aux);
        i++;
    }
```

rs is the ResultSet, historial is the ArrayList and aux is my DTO consisting of the fields shown.

The problem with this is that it ends up filling the ArrayList with the same information 25 times. So I guess that rs.next() does not move one row forward after each iteration. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is you are setting the same object again and again
You need to create a new object inside loop

```
while(rs.next() && i<25){                    
        DTO aux=new DTO();// create aux object here

        aux.setIdVinilo(rs.getInt("id_vinilo"));
        aux.setTitulo(rs.getString("titulo"));
        aux.setAutor(rs.getString("autor"));
        aux.setGenero(rs.getString("genero"));
        aux.setFecha(rs.getInt("fecha"));
        aux.setDiscografica(rs.getString("discografica"));
        aux.setImagen(rs.getString("imagen"));

        historial.add(aux);
        i++;
}
```

Comment: Yep! That was it, thank you so much! I'll accept the answer as soon as it lets me ^^

Comment: @rev_dihazum Thanks for edtiting

Answer (score 0):

Create DTO object inside the while loop